# Python Trunk Create fails to execute when a variable is used for phone_number_sid

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

Python Trunk Create fails to execute when a variable is used for phone_number_sid

My code is below, this same methodology works fine for both the update and the delete functions within twilio's python library but it fails with this particular function. I'm not sure why. It works when I pass a direct phone_number_sid but if I use a variable it fails.

Here's my code.
I do have the environmental variables set for the account sid and auth token as well

```
# Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

with open('insertnamehere.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        # Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
        # and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
        account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
        auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
        client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
        print(test)
        phone_number = client.trunking \
                         .v1 \
                         .trunks('TKIhavetherightvaluehere') \
                         .phone_numbers \
                         .create(phone_number_sid=line)
```

This is the error message I received, but as far as I can tell it's just an issue with the variable being accessed/read incorrectly.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "addSIP.py", line 18, in <module>       
    .create(phone_number_sid=line)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Lib\site-packages\twilio\rest\trunking\v1\trunk\phone_number.py", line 319, in create
    payload = self._version.create(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Lib\site-packages\twilio\base\version.py", line 465, in create
    return self._parse_create(method, uri, response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Lib\site-packages\twilio\base\version.py", line 436, in _parse_create
    raise self.exception(method, uri, response, "Unable to create record")
twilio.base.exceptions.TwilioRestException:
HTTP Error Your request was:

POST /Trunks/TKredacted/PhoneNumbers

Twilio returned the following information:

Unable to create record: The requested resource /Trunks/TKredacted/PhoneNumbers was not found

More information may be available here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404
```

I tried setting the variable to a string
test = str(line)
and then inputting the variable .create(phone_number_sid=test)
but this also did not work.

the file in question is formatted as
PhoneSID
PhoneSID
PhoneSID

and works fine for 2 other scripts with the exact same code. I did notice that this particular code uses the format (phone_number_sid=line) whereas the other examples use .phone_numbers(line) and .incoming_phone_numbers(line) but I am not sure how this impacts the processing of the call.